# Write to txt only prints first result of function

Tags: python

I've written this function, which compares elements of list, which returns the correct results when I print to the terminal

```
def check(samples_avg):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(samples_avg)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(samples_avg)):
            if (np.any(samples_avg[i]) >= np.all(samples_avg[j] * 5)):
                count = count + 1
            if (count == len(samples_avg) - 1):
                return (True)
            else:  
                return (False)
```

However, I want the full results to be written to a .txt file. What I have creates and opens a .txt file but only writes the first result, `False`
and nothing else. I've tried a few other solutions using a loop, but they write `None`

```
output = check(samples_avg)
file = open("sample.txt","w+")
file.write(str(output))
file.close()
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The method itself only returns true or false. What do you expect to be written?

Comment: You might want to take a look at how `return` works. Basically it returns a value once, regardless of the loops you have above it. You want to write your output as a list of True/False instead, right?

Comment: return here transfers control out of check function. Either use different logic to handle how value is returned (i would suggest make a list, append the values of loop and return the list) OR use yield, and then make changes accordingly.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] including expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is going to return only the first return found. If you want to return all values you could create a list, append each result and then write it on the file. Like this:

```
def check(samples_avg):
    count = 0
    results = []
    for i in range(len(samples_avg)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(samples_avg)):
            if (np.any(samples_avg[i]) >= np.all(samples_avg[j] * 5)):
                count = count + 1
            results.append(count == len(samples_avg) - 1)
    return results

output = check(samples_avg)
file = open("sample.txt","w+")
file.write("\n".join(map(str, output)))
file.close()
```